# Doctors losing their licence/ r'shut beit din

Tags: halacha, medicine, beit-din-court

Various sources refer to doctors acting with the permission of the beit din; some suggest that this is a mandatory requirement and that it is forbidden to practice medicine without such permission (eg Aruch ha-Shulchan, YD 336:2; Aseh L'cha Rav 3:6, note 1).

My question is: are there any sources which deal with the revocation of this licence? Any sources which discuss a beit din withdrawing its permission? For instance, because of misconduct or incompetence or dishonesty.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this question. The Aruch Ha-Shulchan (and modern poskim see e.g., [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/13141) and [here](https://medicalhalacha.org/2020/07/13/the-askans-liability/)) writes that nowadays one has to have a **government license** to practice medicine. As such a beit din has no power to revoke such a license and wouldn't be discussing such cases. You might find interesting discussions whether it is allowed to report to the authorities cases of medical malpractice - where I believe the answer to be clearly yes.

Comment: @mbloch that would be true of 19th c. Lithuania... but I don't see anything in the OP suggesting that he'd like to restrict the scope of his question to that time period and place. Ostensibly this is an answerable question.

Comment: Do you know a location where a beit din licenses doctors? If not the question cannot be answered unless it is meant in a historical context

Comment: @mbloch It’s fairly obviously meant in a historical context.